# powershell Get-Winevent change output date format?

Tags: powershell

I'm running this powershell command from a perl script and parsing the output.

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=7001,10,12,13,41,42,1129,5060,5719,6008,7045}| SELECT-Object ID,TimeCreated,MACHINENAME,MESSAGE|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' }  | select -Skip 1"
```

Is there a way to change the format of the TimeGenerated field in the oputput to **2014-08-5 16:09:54** from **8/5/2014 4:09:54 PM**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create values from hashtables at the Select portion of the pipe. This should do what you want:

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=7001,10,12,13,41,42,1129,5060,5719,6008,7045}| SELECT-Object ID,@{label='TimeCreated';expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss")}},MACHINENAME,MESSAGE|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' }  | select -Skip 1"
```

I replaced TimeCreated with `@{label=TimeCreated;expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss")}}`. Let me break that down for you.

label=TimeCreated is what the property name will be going further down the pipe. I simply reused the same name.

expression={ScriptBlock} tells the system what the value for that property will be for each record.

As for the actual scriptblock, in this case we were already working with a [DateTime] object so I used its ToString() method, and specified a format of your design to output it as. That changes it, so it is now a [String] instead of a [DateTime] object, but seeing as you are just converting the whole thing to a CSV a string should do just fine.

**Edit:** You can add a switch into the scriptblock of the hashtable described above, it just gets long and can be hard to follow. I would do something like:

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=7001,10,12,13,41,42,1129,5060,5719,6008,7045}| SELECT-Object ID,@{l='ID Description';e={Switch($_.ID){
    "7001" {"Text1"}
    "10"   {"Text2"}
    "12"   {"Text3"}
    "13"   {"Text4"}
    "41"   {"Text5"}
    "42"   {"Text6"}
    "1129" {"Text7"}
    "5060" {"Text8"}
    "5719" {"Text9"}
    "6008" {"Text10"}
    "7045" {"Text11"}
    }
}},@{label='TimeCreated';expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss")}},MACHINENAME,MESSAGE|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' }  | select -Skip 1"
```

`l=` is short for `label=` and `e=` is short for `expression=`

**Edit2:** More switch info... You could do things based on multiple fields, you would want to do `Switch($_)` and then on each line put your conditions in a scriptblock, so something like:

```
Switch($_){
    {$_.ID -eq "7001" -and $_.Message -match "catastrophic"}{"The dog ate my NetBIOS"}
    {$_.ID -eq "7001" -and $_.Message -match "Lex Luthor"}{"Superman stole my WiFi"}
    {<more conditions>}{<and their resultant values>}
}
```

Comment: awesome ! Thanks. Trying to figure out, if i can add a SWITCH statement to the select list. What i'm trying to do is, for event ID 1, say TEXTXXX, for event ID 2, say TEXTYYY, etc... (derive a text field based on the field ID). Would you happen to know if thats possible?

Comment: Can the expression have multiple fields? Like currently there is a switch statement on the ID field. Is it possible to have maybe an OR condition based on the Message Field. 'ID Description'= (If EventID=X, then X) or ( If Message contains %TXT1%, then Y or If Message contains %TXT2%, then Z)

Comment: Updated, again. If you have more questions about the Switch command, maybe you should post another question to get help with it?

Comment: I just did : [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330481  Could you take a look when time permits? Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an expression in the `Select-Object` command to create a calculated property. Here, I called this new property "Time" and used the `ToString()` method with the `InvariantCulture` to make sure the output is consistent on different computers.

```
Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=7001,10,12,13,41,42,1129,5060,5719,6008,7045} | `
  SELECT-Object -Property ID,@{Name="Time"; Expression = {$_.TimeCreated.Tostring("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)}},MACHINENAME,MESSAGE | `
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' }  | select -first 5
```

Comment: Thx. What if i need to select some Dummy text as another field?

Comment: By dummy text, I suppose you mean a constant value. You can add another calculated property like this `@{Name="Dummy"; Expression={"DummyValue"}}`