# powershell Get-Winevent SWITCH MATCH issue

Tags: powershell

'm running this powershell command and saving the output in a csv.

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=42}| SELECT-Object @{Label = 'TimeCreated'; Expression = {Get-Date $_.TimeCreated -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}},@{Label = 'DayOfWeek'; Expression = {(Get-Date $_.TimeCreated).DayOfWeek}},ID,@{l='ID Description';e={Switch ($_)  { {$_.ID -eq '42'}{'Type=Sleep matched using EventID';break} {$_.MESSAGE -Match 'Sleep Reason: Application API'}{Type='Sleep matched using Message';break}  }}},MESSAGE|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' } | select -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append c:\logs\timeline\TEMP_TimeLine.csv"
```

I get the expected results as below:

```
"2014-05-10 00:00:04","Saturday","42","Type=Sleep matched using EventID","The system is entering sleep.,,Sleep Reason: Application API"
"2014-05-09 00:00:02","Friday","42","Type=Sleep matched using EventID","The system is entering sleep.,,Sleep Reason: Application API"
"2014-05-08 00:00:02","Thursday","42","Type=Sleep matched using EventID","The system is entering sleep.,,Sleep Reason: Application API"
```

But, if i switch the positions of the two case statements inside the switch, i'm not getting the expected output(The derived field 'ID Description' is blank). I am trying to get mix of string matches on the message field and EventID field to be working together.
This is what i'm trying:

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=42}| SELECT-Object @{Label = 'TimeCreated'; Expression = {Get-Date $_.TimeCreated -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}},@{Label = 'DayOfWeek'; Expression = {(Get-Date $_.TimeCreated).DayOfWeek}},ID,@{l='ID Description';e={Switch ($_)  {  {$_.MESSAGE -Match 'Sleep Reason: Application API'}{Type='Sleep matched using Message';break} {$_.ID -eq '42'}{'Type=Sleep matched using EventID';break} }}},MESSAGE|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' } | select -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append c:\logs\timeline\TEMP_TimeLine.csv"
```

The Message field clearly has the string 'Sleep Reason: Application API' as we can see from the first output. Wondering whats going on here... Any clues powershell experts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, two issues I see:

A) You're probably breaking your own script. I'll get to that in a sec.
B) You're missing a `'` on the $_.Message line. `Type='Sleep` should be `'Type=Sleep`

Ok, back to point A. I'll start with `;break`. In 99% of cases don't do it, you'll make the scripting gods angry, and you wouldn't like them when they're angry. In most cases you want to use `;Continue` instead. Break literally breaks out of things, and depending on where it's used it can break out of parent loops entirely stopping part way through a set of things. Continue on the other hand moves to the end of the current loop, skipping anything else. Same thing? Kinda, sorta, but Continue won't break a ForEach-Object loop like Break will.

So, with that said, let's try this in your switch:

```
Switch ($_)  { 
    {$_.ID -eq '42'}{'Type=Sleep matched using EventID';continue} 
    {$_.MESSAGE -Match 'Sleep Reason: Application API'}{'Type=Sleep matched using Message';continue}
}
```

Ok, that's great, along with the whole `'` issue in point B that would probably fix the code in general.

So, with that said, why are you running it like that? Dear lord, running an insanely long one liner is just crazy. Save it to a .PS1 file, and if you're calling it from a batch file then call the script file, but ug, that's just hard to work with in general, it's no wonder you missed the `'` in the middle of that line. If you are calling it from a batch file, name it GetSleepLogs.ps1 (or whatever you want, just modify the file name in the command) and try this:

```
PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File GetSleepLogs.ps1
```

**Edit:** I didn't like the convertto-CSV | select -skip 1 | %{ %_ -replace ...} | Out-File thing, it just seemed clunky to me. Also, all the impromptu hashtables on the Select command were a little hard to follow. Check out this alternative that creates 1 object with several properties, and then just pipes that to Export-CSV with the -append and -NoTypeInformation switches set which should just tack it to the bottom of an existing CSV file.

```
Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=42}| ForEach{[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    'TimeCreated' = Get-Date $_.TimeCreated -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
    'DayOfWeek' = (Get-Date $_.TimeCreated).DayOfWeek
    'ID' = $_.ID
    'ID Description' = Switch($_){
                        {$_.ID -eq '42' -AND $_.Message -match 'Sleep Reason: Application API'}{'Type=Sleep matched using EventID and Message';continue}
                        {$_.ID -eq '42'}{'Type=Sleep matched using EventID';continue}
                        {$_.Message -match 'Sleep Reason: Application API'}{'Type=Sleep matched using Message';continue}}
    'MESSAGE' = $_.Message.replace("`r`n`r`n","`r`n") -replace "((?<!`")`r`n|`n|`r)", ","
}}|Export-Csv C:\temp\TimeLine.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
```

Comment: If you really don't want to execute the code from a file, write it out multi-line in a ps1 as normal and when you're done, base64 encode it, then use the `-EncodedCommand` parameter. There's not much reason to avoid using a file, but if you must, this works well for long code. See `powershell.exe /?` for a snippet that can be used to encode the file.